# POST request origins

Tags: php, security, post

Is there any way by which i could know exactly which server a POST request has originated from ?

I'm trying to implement a method wherein i could check that a specific request has originated from my website, and hence this will help me keep my website secure

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the referrer? The page where the user came from?

Comment: Did you really mean "originated from my website", or did you mean "originated from a form on a page sent to the browser from my website"? They're very different things.

Comment: Do NOT rely on the referer header. It cannot be trusted and is often stripped in firewalls for leaking information about internal systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement Cross Site Request Forgery protection, in which you need to make sure the request originated from HTML delivered from your web server. Do not rely on the referer header for this as it is often stripped in firewalls, and can be manipulated.

See OWASP for some good sources on how to implement this kind of protection. Basically it goes like this:

1. Generate a secure random value and stick it on the user's session
2. For every HTML form, include this value as a hidden value ()
3. Whenever a POST request comes back to your server, check that the value from the hidden field, is the same as the one in the user's session. Reject the request if it isn't.

Because the alue is unique per user, an attacker could not simply forge a form with prepopulated values, and trick the user into automatically posting it with javascript. The request would be rejected as the attacker would not know which value to include for the hidden field in his forged form.

Comment: "Whenever a POST request comes back to your server, check that the value from the hidden field, is the same as the one in the user's session. " --- well, you downvoted me and did not described why and how to check **the origin** of the request.

Comment: zerkms: So you downvoted me because I downvoted you?
I tried to look beyond the question. "I'm trying to implement a method wherein i could check that a specific request has originated from my website, and hence this will help me keep my website secure"
He wants to check on _his website_, whether a request originated from _his website_

Comment: @Erlend: you tried to look beyond the quesion but not beyond my answer. I did not say he need not use CSRF tokens protection (which is must-have practice in any case), but in some unknown reason you treated my answer as the one that recommends to avoid them.

Comment: @zerkms: See my comment to your answer.

Comment: @Erlend: I did. And I think that I (and you) behaved like a child in this thread. I'm sorry too

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention

Answer (score 1):

You want `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-determine-retrieve-visitors-ip-address-use-php-code-programming/